# Unity. Disable collision physics but have method for collision called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Basically, i have player object and bunch of other. For this moment they all have `RigitBody2D`, and colliders, code for creating:

```
        obj = new GameObject();
        obj.tag = "web";    
        obj.name = "web";
        float randomX = Random.Range (Utilities.getMainCameraBounds ().min.x, Utilities.getMainCameraBounds ().max.x);
        float randomY = Random.Range (Utilities.getMainCameraBounds ().min.y, Utilities.getMainCameraBounds ().max.y);
        obj.transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, randomY);
        obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f);
        collider = obj.AddComponent <BoxCollider2D>();
        body = obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        body.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
        joint = obj.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D> ();

        renderer = obj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        renderer.sortingOrder = 1;

        renderer.sprite = Resources.Load("Textures/dot_net", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

Purpose for this is to catch collision like this :

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.transform.tag == "web") {
        Player.getInstance().joint(collision.rigidbody);
    }
}
```

After player collides with some of those objects, method `joint` called, it's purpose to connect `player` and `web` with `HingeJoint2D` to simulate pendulum behvior. Code of `joint`:

```
public void joint(Rigidbody2D body) {
    WebCollection.getInstance ().turnOffColliders (body.gameObject);
    HingeJoint2D hingeJoint = webLine.getObject ().AddComponent<HingeJoint2D> ();
    hingeJoint.connectedBody = body;
    hingeJoint.anchor = new Vector2 (0.00120592f, 0.1921938f);
    hingeJoint.connectedAnchor = new Vector2 (0.1939605f, 0.03025406f);
}
```

Pendulum behavior is working just fine, but in moment of it, or just when player is moving towards web, other `web` objects are colliding with it, creating real colliding behavior(like crushing into each other)

**My goal:** i want `web` objects to react on the collision(calling method above), but on the screen to player just go throw them.

**What i've already tried:** I wanted to turnOff other objects bodies (`WebCollection.getInstance ().turnOffColliders (body.gameObject);)` and after pendulum movement is over, to turn them back, but it causes very strange behavior.

What also can be a solution is to manually checking if player is colliding with `web` object right now, and handle it, but this is to costly i think.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Colliders to be Triggers?

Comment: I'm very new to Unity, and i'm afraid i do not understand you

Comment: But i'll find some info about it

Comment: When you assign a collider component to a gameobject there is a checkbox in the collider component that says "Is Trigger". If you set the colliders to be triggers, they will not be physical colliders, but call an OnTriggerEnter event, when colliders touch (see also: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

Comment: @xyLe_, i will try it and answer you shortly after, thx for the tip

Comment: There is also a short introduction on Colliders as Triggers by Unity, maybe that helps: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers

Comment: Is your problem that the web objects are colliding with themselves and you want them to only collide with the player ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem, it's working as intended, need to realize now how actually HingeJoint is working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put my comment into an answer for those finding your question:

If you want to have Colliders that only trigger events and do not physically collide with other Colliders, then what you want are **Triggers**. To make a `Collider` a trigger you check the *Is Trigger* checkbox of the collider component in the inspector (you can also set it via script with the `Collider.IsTrigger` boolean property).

To do something when the trigger fires, use the `OnTrigger` events (`OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerExit`, `OnTriggerStay`) (see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)

There is also a short introduction to Colliders as Triggers by unity: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers